# How to write the xpath for iframe tag

Tags: selenium

Xpath for IFramce to capture the credit card details on Iframe pages

I have tried the below XPath to point out the credit card number details, though the details are not capturing through my XPath.

IFRAME

```
[xpath://iframe[contains(@id,'spreedly-number-frame')]]

xpath://form[@id='number-form']//input[@id='card_number']
```

[image: Iframe dic details]

Comment: did you switch to iframe first before accessing the element??

Comment: what error you getting?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something in iframe, you must switch in it by

```
Driver = Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@id,'spreedly-number-frame')]"));
```

to return back to main page use

```
Driver = Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```